# React-JS TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined" if I try to call  setState in a function (edit or save).
It works if I declare an arrow function instead, but I do not understand why?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Note extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            editing: false
        }
    }

    edit (){
        this.setState({ editing: true })
    }

    save() {
        this.setState({ editing: false })
    }

    renderEditNote() {
        return (
            <div className="note">
                <textarea></textarea>
                <button onClick={this.save}>SAVE</button>
            </div>
        )
    }

    renderDisplayNote() {
        return (
            <div className="note">
                <p>{this.props.children}</p>
                <span>
                    <button onClick={this.edit}>Edit</button>
                    <button onClick={this.remove}>X</button>
                </span>
            </div>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return this.state.editing ? this.renderEditNote() : this.renderDisplayNote()
    }
}

export default Note
```

Comment: Are you sure `this` is set?

Comment: The value of `this` depends on *how* a function is *called*. See also [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196)

Comment: thank you for the link, it brought me clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) `this` for `edit` and `save` functions so it doesn't get lost when called-back by the `onClick`.

For example:

```
 <button onClick={this.edit.bind(this)}>Edit</button>
```

Or you can do it in the `constructor` as:

`this.edit = this.edit.bind(this);`

Comment: thank you very much, worked this  way.

Answer (score 0):

To make it works, you should do

```
this.save.bind(this)
this.edit.bind(this)
this.remove.bind(this)
```

You have not bind it yet, so the this in your method edit(), save() and remove() is not the Note class.
You can do console.log(this) in those methods to understand why